# I18n how to get translated model name in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I have a header in a page where I would like to appear something like this:

'Aanpassen bewoner'
'Aanpassen gebruiker'

'Aanpassen' is dutch for Edit.
'bewoner', 'gebruiker' are translated class names of Senior, User.

I have translated the active record classes in the file like this:

```
nl:
  activerecord:
    models:
      user:
        one: 'Gebruiker'
```

Is there a way to write the header once in the views (or in helper class) so it takes the model it currently is showing and shows the translation?  Ideally I would only have one line of code which I could use in all edit views of all classes (as long as they are translated of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to guess the current model (which is the hardest part I think) from the current controller name and then you can try to I18n it. The following helper does just that:

```
# application_helper.rb
def translated_model_name(model = controller_name)
  model_class = model.to_s.singularize.camelize
  Object.const_defined?(model_class) ? model_class.constantize.model_name.human : model.to_s
end
```

The helper tries to guess the model name and then uses the `model_name.human` method for translating it (see [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models)). It can be used in your template this way:

```
# e.g. in users/index.html.erb
<%= translated_model_name %>
# => prints translation for the :user model

# whereas in seniors/show.html.erb
<%= translated_model_name %>
# => prints translation for the :senior model
```

If the model name cannot be automatically guessed from the controller name, you can override it with a parameter to the helper:

```
# e.g. in some_non_model_path/index.html.erb
<%= translated_model_name(:user) %>
# => prints translation for the :user model
```

Answer (score 0):

Use #underscore to to that. See the Inflections module. So in the controller,

```
underscore(your_object.model.to_s)
```

will convert YourTerrificModel to your_terrific_model. To translate:

```
I18n::t("activerecord.model.#{underscore(your_object.model.to_s)}", count: 1)
```

will give you the translated name of the class. A count > 1 or a count == 0 will give you the other forms.

Comment: `I18n::t("activerecord.model.#{underscore(your_object.model.to_s)}", count: 1)` did not work for me, but `I18n.t("activerecord.models.#{your_object.class.to_s.underscore}", count: 1)` worked. "underscore" is a method of the class String and the method "model" does not exist.